# Keep getting this message on start up "An error occured while mounting ext3"

Tags: partitioning

I was following this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639) to install Oracle 11gr2 on ubuntu 11.10

As mentioned in the above link #6 Resize the Root Partition, I created a new partition for free space of 18GB with ext3 type of partition.

And the link says follow the below steps after partitioning:

```
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab_`date +%N`
uuid=`blkid | grep oraclexe | awk '{print $3}'`
uuid=`echo $uuid | tr -d '\042'`
echo $uuid
echo "$uuid  /u01  ext3  errors=remount-ro 0 1" >> /etc/fstab
```

But here is where i got confused on what exactly he is asking me to do..So i just ran these commands in the Command line..each command one by one..

and when i restart i see the messages:

> An error occured while mounting ext3 Press S to skip mounting or M for
>   manual recovery

Tutorial also says like i have to configure UUID and all that but the steps are not clear on how to do that?

And this is how my fstab looks like [link](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0C0A)

Please help me on how to resolve this issue..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem (paste from `/etc/fstab`)

```
/u01  ext3  errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=3dc778b4-509c-41d9-a010-2b53417de528  /u01  ext3  errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

The first line (`/u01....`) is incorrect, it's missing the device to mount; it's redundant when you have line 2, so just comment it out with a `#` in front.

Please paste the outputs of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo mount` after you have done that and rebooted.

Comment: It worked fine..Please find the below links http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0C0S   http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0C0X

Comment: Can you look at the above links and confirm if there is anything else wrong with the configuration/partition

Comment: Both look good to me.

Comment: Happy to help! :)